# How do add an excel file to an automated email i send?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

`CLOSE all
*Here's an example of creating and sending email by automating Outlook:

```
            LOCAL oOutlook, oNameSpace, oMailItem

              oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                oNameSpace = oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

            oMailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(0)

            #DEFINE CR CHR(13)
       WITH oMailItem
         .Subject = "Daily Reports"
     .Body = " Your daily report is there." + CR + ;
      .Recipients.Add("John.doe@test.com")
     ENDWITH

   oMailItem.Send()
```

*I am looking for a way to add an excel file to this little program?`

Comment: Please provide more details to your question, it's really unclear to understand what you really want to do and what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method creates a new attachment in the Attachments collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, if you need to attach an excel file, you have to pass a file path to the `Add` method:

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.xslx", _ 
 olByValue, 1, "Test" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

So, in your sample code just need to add a single line of code:

```
     WITH oMailItem
        .Subject = "Daily Reports"
        .Body = " Your daily report is there." + CR + ;
        .Recipients.Add("John.doe@test.com")
        .Attachments.Add("C:\Test.xslx", olByValue, 1, "Excel file" ) 
     ENDWITH
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. However, it will only work for that specific email, you will need to specify other paths, for every other email. Assuming you'll be needing more than one.

```
LOCAL oOutlook, oNameSpace, oMailItem

    oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    oNameSpace = oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    
    oMailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    #DEFINE CR CHR(13)
    WITH oMailItem
      .Subject = "Daily Reports"
      .Body = " Your daily report is there." + CR +
      .Recipients.Add("John.doe@test.com")
      
      ' Attach your Excel file
      .Attachments.Add("C:\path\to\file.xlsx")
    ENDWITH
    
    oMailItem.Send()
```